# Imagick Command Line to PHP Class

Tags: php, image, filter, imagick

i have a shared host that contains imagick bundled with php.
... And, i want to put some image filters for my clients while using my photo application.

Searching on the web, i found http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-instagram-filters-with-php/ ... but this uses 'convert', and 'convert' program was not in PATH, so i can't use the code of article.

The question is, how to convert these commands to PHP Imagick class ? http://php.net/imagick

Answer (score 0):

> The question is, how to convert these commands to PHP Imagick class ?

That is merely straight forward. You need:

1. The [code of the class](https://github.com/webarto/instagraph)
2. The [PHP Imagick Manual](http://php.net/imagick)
3. The description of all [ImageMagick: Command-line Tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)

You then to through the code, pick out the sequence of the commandline calls used for the effect and look up in the PHP manual which methods can be used to achieve the same.

You can also search the site here a bit, for some more complex operations, this has been asked before, so you should find enough resources.

And that's basically it. You can start with one of the more simple filters and add what you did so far to your question so it's more clear into which problems you run.

Comment: Isn't there any tool to do that? Or at least a table with all examples, command line on left, php class on right?

Comment: @psychobrm: The PHP manual is open to edit for everybody. If you would like to add such a guide, I'd say it's greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function of PHP Imagick class 
Process is modulate which is used in kelvin(), nashville(), toaster() and gotham()

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.modulateimage.php

You can look for another method in php.net for every process or parameter which is used in command.